# Regex Pattern for Not allow all same characters even separated by single special character

Tags: java, regex

Trying to create the regex for the below conditions, I have tried the one regex it's working as expected other than one condition as it does not allow duplicates even separated by particular Char &.

1. Allow Alpha Numeric characters with a minimum of 12 and a maximum of 14
2. No special characters are allowed other than & ( only one)
3. Not Allow all the same characters even separated by &
4. Length is same between 12 to 14 even including the &

ex: 111111111111 not allowed as all are the same characters

```
1111111&11111 not allowed as all are the same characters even & is there

111111111112 allowed 

1111111&11112 allowed

ABC123567GHDG4 allowed
```

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)(?=.{11,13}$)[0-9]*(?:[&][0-9]+)?$
```

The above regex is working other than the case 1111111&11111

tried the below regex as well, it works the condition as it's not allowing the same characters

But it allows the & beginning and end of the string and not allowed Alphabets

```
^(?!&?(\d)(?:&?\1)+$)(?=.{12,14}$)\d*(?:&\d*)?$
```

We do not allow the `"&"` at the beginning and end of the string
And it needs to allow the `Captial Alpha character` along with `numerics`.

```
ABC123567GHDG4 allowed 

ABC1235&67GHD allowed

ABCDEFGHIJKLR allowed

1254789563254 allowed

125478&563254 allowed

125478556325& not allowed as ends with &

&125478556325 not allowed as starts with &

ABCDEFGHIJKL& not allowed as ends with &

&ABCDEFGHIJKL not allowed as start with &
```

Comment: Sorry one case missed in the questions same character means not only digits even alpha like AAAAAAAAAAAA not allow

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75949772/3832970) (I removed the comment above), it has the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(?=.{12,14}$)(?!([a-zA-Z\d])(?:&?\1)+$)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:&[a-zA-Z\d]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aFpfwv/3)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{12,14}$)` - the length of the string must be between 12 and 14 chars
- `(?!([a-zA-Z\d])(?:&?\1)+$)` - the string cannot have identical alphanumeric chars eventually separated with a `&` char at any position
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:&[a-zA-Z\d]+)?` - one or more alphanumeric chars followed with an optional sequence of a `&` char followed with one or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Nothing in the question talks about specifically digits; that `\d` should presumably be `[0-9A-Z]` or `\\w`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Correct, the only example provided got me off the track.

Comment: Sorry one case missed in the questions same character means not only digits even alpha like AAAAAAAAAAAA
 not allow

Comment: @HarinathaReddy `AAAAAAAAAAAA` is not allowed with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/aFpfwv/4).

Comment: Yes I referred to the earlier one in the comments of the question, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern:

```
/^([A-Z0-9])(?!(\1|&)+$)(?=.{11,13}$)[A-Z0-9]*(?:[&][A-Z0-9]+)?$/gm
```

It's modified version of your pattern, I've only updated the negative look-ahead part to `(?!(\1|&)+$)` (not allow repeated of first letter or '&' letter).

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hfcNuE/1)